# Need advice for a project

Tags: project

I have a project idea in mind and I don't know how to achieve it. Let me explain. My idea is to create a web app that suggests travel destination ideas depending on dates and a budget.

But as far as I know all flight or hotel APIs available need a destination as a query parameter, so I'm stuck here. A workaround could be to create my own dataset of flight and hotel price, but I have no idea how to achieve this effectively and this is gonna take time and money to collect everything, so I'm not sure I can afford to do this.

What do you think? Have you another idea to help me to achieve this idea?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic